# Many-to-One records Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to turn many records into one per message. I tried many things like custom reducing and aggregators, but they all still send one-to-one records back out. For example I would like to convert many strings into just one string. If my stream is messages with the same key, but different values, "the", "sky", "is", "blue", then I would like to outback back one concatenation of them in a new topic "the,sky,is,blue,". What I am instead getting is 4 messages "the,", "the, sky,", "the,sky, is,", "the,sky,is,blue,". When I send a second message to the kafka consumer, it will concatenate on the previous aggregation and I eventually receive this "the,sky,is,blue,the,sky,is,blue,"

I also tried using a custom storebuilder and changing a lot of the settings to see if that would do anything.

```
     Map<String, String> changelogConfig = new HashMap<>();
            changelogConfig.put("message.down.conversion.enable", "true");
            changelogConfig.put("flush.messages", "0");
            changelogConfig.put("flush.ms", "0");

     StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> aggStoreSupplier = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                    Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("AggStore"),
                    Serdes.String(),
                    Serdes.String())
                    .withLoggingEnabled(changelogConfig);

     KStream<String, String> results = source // single message get processed and eventually i get these string results I need to concatenate
            .groupByKey() // this kgroupedstream has the N records, which was how many were sent in the message
            .reduce(new Reducer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String apply(String aggValue, String value) {
                            return value + "," + aggValue;
                        }
                    }, Materialized.as("AggStore"))
                    .toStream();

     results.to("results", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
     final Topology topology = builder.build(); // to describe topology
     System.out.println(topology.describe()); // to print description
     final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

     final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
     // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
     Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
       @Override
       public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
       });

       try {
            streams.cleanUp();
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
       } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
       }
     System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I also just started looking at Processor API documentation just now. So if anyone could point me into any example using that would be just as great.

Comment: How do you know that the first "batch" of messages and the second "batch" of message should result in two output messages (the both have the same key?). Using the DSL, you might want to apply some windowing? For get only the "final" result of a windowed-aggregation, you can use `suppress()` operator.

Comment: I know the batches are batches because they originated as single messages. I do a one-to multiple records step before all this, and now I just want to combine my multiple records back into one to send back to my API that produced this data.

I just tried windowed aggregation, but I am not able to immediately close the window. I would just like to suppress on a regular reduce method. I also don't want to store the result of the reduce method because Kafka won't be doing anything with it, just my API.

Comment: Actually I was following up with some how do I know it's a batch. And I actually am not correctly rekeying my records after processing them. I will fix that and retry everything.

Comment: I see -- overall it seems that the DSL might not work for you. Instead, you should use the Processor API that gives you more flexibility in stiching the original records pieces together.